# Find minimum values of numpy columns

Tags: python, numpy, loops, min, numpy-ndarray

Looking to print the minimum values of numpy array columns.
I am using a loop in order to do this.
The array is shaped (20, 3) and I want to find the min values of columns, starting with the first (i.e. col_value=0)

I have coded

```
col_value=0
for col_value in X:
    print(X[:, col_value].min)
    col_value += 1
```

However, it is coming up with an error

`"arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type"`

How do I fix this?

Comment: What is `X`? And what error is it giving you? On what line?

Comment: @Grismar  the error is "arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type". X is a numpy array shaped (20, 3)

Comment: `col_value` is a row of `X`. It makes no sense to use it as a column index.  Practice with some simpler iterations.

Answer (score 3):

Let me suggest an alternative approach that you might find useful. numpy `min()` has `axis` argument that you can use to find min values along various 
dimensions.

Example:

```py
X = np.random.randn(20, 3)
print(X.min(axis=0))
```

prints numpy array with minimum values of X columns.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need col_value=0 nor do you need col_value+=1.

```
x = numpy.array([1,23,4,6,0])
print(x.min())
```

EDIT:
Sorry didn't see that you wanted to iterate through columns.

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,2], [3,4]])

for col in X.T:
    print(col.min())
```

Comment: when I do that, it shows <built-in method min of numpy.ndarray object at 0x1a250098a0>

Comment: I need the col_value=0 and +=1 as I need to use a loop to find the minimum for each column of the numpy array

Comment: I'm assuming that you come from a different language (like c++) but those aren't necessary in python. https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score -1):

Transposing the axis of the matrix is one the best solution.

```
X=np.array([[11,2,14],
            [5,15, 7],
            [8,9,20]])
X=X.T #Transposing the array
for i in X:
    print(min(i))
```