# minimum value for all columns in a 2D numpy array in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D array and I want to find the minimum value for each column which coressponds to lower bound on each varaible.

My attempt is

```
 lb = np.array([WALL[:,0].min(), WALL[:,1].min(), WALL[:,2].min(),WALL[:,3].min()])
```

Example:

```
WALL = array([[ 2.00000e-01,  8.75000e-02,  5.68548e-03,  4.85592e-03],
       [ 3.10000e+00,  8.50000e-03, -5.68528e-03, -4.85579e-03],
       [ 2.75000e+00,  5.23500e-01, -7.27231e-03,  1.74665e-03],
       [ 1.25000e+00,  8.65500e-01,  6.91469e-03,  2.86479e-03],
       [ 4.15000e+00,  8.66500e-01,  1.74417e-03,  7.26701e-03]])

lb = np.array([WALL[:,0].min(), WALL[:,1].min(), WALL[:,2].min(),WALL[:,3].min()])
lb
array([ 0.2       ,  0.0085    , -0.00727231, -0.00485579])
```

Is there a better way than this especially  I have a lot of columns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find minimum values of numpy columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61995705/find-minimum-values-of-numpy-columns)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the axis to take the min over in `.min()` :

```
print(Wall.min(axis=0))
```